# Entity Framework - saving db changes not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model, savechanges

When submitting a form and passing in my model (Forms) I am trying to save the changes to my DB.

Forms model has a `PeopleInvolved` object as a property.

The model is updated successfully, the changes also get added to the `peopleInvolved` object successfully, however, the `SaveChanges()` call doesn't save anything.

.NET Framework 4.5.1 - EF 6.1.1

```
public class Forms
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public PeopleInvolved PeopleInvolved { get; set; }     
}

public async Task<ActionResult> EditForm(Forms model, string returnUrl)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ApplicationUser user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);

    if (model.PeopleInvolved != null)
    {
        PeopleInvolved peopleInvolved = _db.PeopleInvolved.Single(x => x.FormId == user.FormId);
        peopleInvolved = model.PeopleInvolved;

        _db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl + "?PeopleInvolved?Success");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add or update?

Comment: I'm trying to update - ideally without having to manually assign each property to corresponding model property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update like this.
If you have to override model.PeopleInvolved.FormId with user.FormId update that property.

```
db.PeopleInvolved.Attach(model.PeopleInvolved);
db.Entry(model.PeopleInvolved)).State =  System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;    
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Awesome, works a charm - I already tried this but **AFTER** I'd retrieved a row so was getting a duplicate primary key.

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually change anything from the database.

Your call to the database returned a `PeopleInvolved` object and stored a reference to it in the `peopleInvolved` variable. Then you change that variable to be a reference to the `PeopleInvolved` property on the model object. You never actually change the object returned from the database call.

Simplistic solution is to do something like

```
peopleInvolved.Property1 = model.PeopleInvolved.Property1;
peopleInvolved.Property2 = model.PeopleInvolved.Property2;
```

to update the actual object that was returned from the database.

Comment: ARGH you are totally correct! I was trying to get around assigning each property individually. Thank you!